# How to get the sum of each different object in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I read a sjon with few objects, on this example I have two but they could be more:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: 
0:   {
  "date":"3/13/20",
  "ricoverati_con_sintomi":4435,
  "terapia_intensiva":650,
  "totale_ospedalizzati":5085,
  "isolamento_domiciliare":2647,
  " …"
}   "date":   "3/13/20",
   "ricoverati_con_sintomi":   4435,
   "terapia_intensiva":   650
   "totale_ospedalizzati":   5085
   "isolamento_domiciliare":   2647
   "totale_attualmente_positivi":   7732
   "nuovi_attualmente_positivi":   836
   "dimessi_guariti":   1198
   "deceduti":   890
   "totale_casi":   9820
   "tamponi":   32700
   "__proto__":   Object1:   {
  "date":"3/14/20",
  "ricoverati_con_sintomi":4898,
  "terapia_intensiva":732,
  "totale_ospedalizzati":5630,
  "isolamento_domiciliare":3429,
  " …"
}   2:   {
  "date":"3/15/20",
  "ricoverati_con_sintomi":5500,
  "terapia_intensiva":767,
  "totale_ospedalizzati":6267,
  "isolamento_domiciliare":3776,
  " …"
}   3:   {
  "date":"3/16/20",
  "ricoverati_con_sintomi":6171,
  "terapia_intensiva":823,
  "totale_ospedalizzati":6994,
  "isolamento_domiciliare":3867,
  " …"
}   "length":   4
"__proto__":   Array(0)
(index):234 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

This is how I am looping to push each value into a global set of arrays

```
$.each( customJsonData, function( key, value ) {
   for (d = 0; d<value.length; d++) {
      var dataSingle = value[d].date;
      labels.push(dataSingle);
      terapia_intensiva.push(value[d].terapia_intensiva);    
      totale_attualmente_positivi.push(value[d].totale_attualmente_positivi);
      nuovi_attualmente_positivi.push(value[d].nuovi_attualmente_positivi);
      dimessi_guariti.push(value[d].dimessi_guariti);
      deceduti.push(value[d].deceduti);
      totale_casi.push(value[d].totale_casi);
   }
 });
```

But what I'd need is also the tot of each single `object`, inside each `obj` I have:

```
0:{
   "date":"3/17/20",
   "ricoverati_con_sintomi":36,
   "terapia_intensiva":4,
   "totale_ospedalizzati":40,
   "isolamento_domiciliare":75,
   "…"
} 1:{
   "date":"3/18/20",
   "ricoverati_con_sintomi":42,
   "terapia_intensiva":7,
   "totale_ospedalizzati":49,
   "isolamento_domiciliare":83,
   "…"
} 2:{
   "date":"3/19/20",
   "ricoverati_con_sintomi":43,
   "terapia_intensiva":9,
   "totale_ospedalizzati":52,
   "isolamento_domiciliare":152,
   "…"
} 3:{
   "date":"3/20/20",
   "ricoverati_con_sintomi":56,
   "terapia_intensiva":15,
   "totale_ospedalizzati":71,
   "isolamento_domiciliare":217,
   "…"
} 4:{
   "date":"3/21/20",
   "ricoverati_con_sintomi":65,
   "terapia_intensiva":16,
   "totale_ospedalizzati":81,
   "isolamento_domiciliare":240,
   "…"
}
```

Each of them is structured like this:

```
0:
  date: "3/17/20"
  ricoverati_con_sintomi: 36
  terapia_intensiva: 4
  totale_ospedalizzati: 40
  isolamento_domiciliare: 75
  totale_attualmente_positivi: 115
  nuovi_attualmente_positivi: 10
  dimessi_guariti: 0
  deceduti: 2
  totale_casi: 117
  tamponi: 1003
```

What I am looking for is:

```
Obj 0:
   tot. terapia_intensiva
   tot. totale_attualmente_positivi
   tot. nuovi_attualmente_positivi
   tot. dimessi_guariti
   tot. deceduti
   tot. totale_casi
```

And do so for each object we might have in the loop.

And then I get the totals of each like this:

```
array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
```

But this is the total of all not the total of each single obj of each single piece in the json

Comment: can you post example output i am getting bit confused with your explanation

Comment: @CodeManiac to make it simple example: json with 3 objects, each objects have sub objects, get separated total of each sub object of each main object and save it separately to access it

Comment: Can you paste a sample input and output in an exact "JSON" structure? Your explanation is still confusing. Even better if you could create an executable example with the input and what you have tried so far

Comment: correct me if am wrong, you want a total of each key ? i.e `"{ ricoverati_con_sintomi": 78,
  "terapia_intensiva": 11,
  "totale_ospedalizzati": 89,
  "isolamento_domiciliare": 158 }`

Comment: @CodeManiac yes exactly, that's what I am looking for. Thing is these values are related to each date. And dates and so their corresponding obj (what you wrote) are part of each single main object

Comment: @Vandesh the json structure is what I have in the question, first bit is the console.log of the main json we get, then second shows what is inside each obj we get, and the third is what we have inside each of them